Averaging a function in 2D when it is independent of the second coordinate
Consider the following expression
$$A_{ij}^* = \overline{A(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})}\delta_{ij} + \overline{A(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})\partial_{y_{i}}a_j(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})},$$
where $\overline{v(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})} := \frac{1}{|V|}\int_V v(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) dV_{\mathbf{y}}$ is the average with respect to the second argument, and $a_j$ are smooth and periodic solutions of the following cell problems:
$$\nabla_y \cdot (A \nabla_y a_j) = -\partial_{y_i}A \ \ \text{in } V_0.$$
Simplifying the setting by restricting ourselves into $\mathbf x, \mathbf y \in \mathbb R^2$ and $V_0 = [0,1]^2$, how does the form for $A_{ij}$ simplify if $A = A(x_1,x_2, y_1)$ (i.e. it does not depend on $y_2$ of $\mathbf y = (y_1, y_2)$)?

I could answer a simpler question when $A = A(\mathbf x)$ is independent of $\mathbf y$ overall (in this case $A^* = A$), but this case seems to be a little more involved.

I have tried starting with $i=j=1$. Then,
$$A_{11} = \int_{0}^1 A(\mathbf x, y_1)dy_1 + \int_0^1\int_0^1 A(\mathbf x, y_1) \partial_{y_1}a_1(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) \, dy_1dy_2.$$
I tried simplifying the second integral as
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 A(\mathbf x, y_1) \partial_{y_1}a_1(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) \, dy_1dy_2 &= \int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 A(\mathbf x,y_1)\partial_{y_1}a_1(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) dy_1\right)dy_2 \\
&= \int_0^1\left(A(\mathbf x,y_1)a_1(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)\big|_{y_1=0}^{y_1=1} + \int_0^1 a_1(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)\partial_{y_1}A(\mathbf x, y_1) dy_1\right)dy_2 \\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1 a_1(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\partial_{y_1}A(\mathbf x, y_1) \,dy_1dy_2
\end{align}
$$
However, it does not seem to go far this way.
We could simplify the cell problems for $a_j$ a little bit using $A = A(\mathbf x, y_1)$ as
$$\partial_{y_1}(A\partial_{y_1}a_1) + A\partial_{y_2}^2 a_1 = - \partial_{y_1}A$$
and $$\partial_{y_1}(A\partial_{y_1}a_2) + A\partial_{y_2}^2 a_2 = 0$$. However, once again, I cannot see a way to go.
My intuition says that since $a_j$ are completely determined by $A$, they should also be independent of $y_2$ (or similar behaviour).

Any help to obtain a nice formula for $A_{ij}$ is appreciated.
